# USING keyword in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table A with the following definition in MySQL

```
----------------------------------
id    c_id     t_id
-------------------------------
```

where c_id references cid on another table B with the following definition

```
================================================
id cid cname
=================================================
```

So i am issuing the following query

```
select group_concat(cname) as list
from A join B using (cid)
where t_id="something";
```

But I m getting the following error

```
Unknown column "cid" in from clause
```

I tried changing it to "c_id", but that doesnt seem to work either..

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`USING` in MySQL is just a short form for a standard `ON` clause, and only works when the column name is identical in both tables.

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> The USING(column_list) clause names a list of columns that must exist
>   in both tables.

Instead, do this:

```
select group_concat(B.cname) as list 
from A 
inner join B on A.c_id = B.cid 
where A.t_id = 'something';
```

Answer (score 2):

Both columns need the same name: either c_id or cid
Then the using clause will work

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select group_concat(cname) as list
from A join B using (c_id)
where t_id="something";
```

but `c_id` is  common both table .